# How to echo "some text" and result of function in one line?

Tags: bash, scripts, echo

I'm starting to learn Bash scripting. And I had a question.
The code below is working fine,

```
Echo "Here is your current directory: "
pwd
```

but what if I want to have the result of pwd to be written in the same line as explanation string? How to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a *command substitution*

```
echo "Here is your current directory: $(pwd)"
```

However you might want to get into the habit of preferring `printf` over `echo`

```
printf 'Here is your current directory: %s\n' "$(pwd)"
```

---

Note: you could just tell `echo` not to include the terminating newline e.g.

```
echo -n "Here is your current directory: "
pwd
```

but it's not recommended - see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: Nice and complete answer, I have nothing to add except an upvote :)